# Having trouble finding error in my Assembly Language program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm having trouble finding error in this assembly code:

```
extern accept1,str1,concate,str2,substring

section .data

msg db "1.Concate 2 strings",10,"2.Find substring",10,"3.Exit",10,"Enter choice: "
msglen equ $-msg

section .bss
cnt resd 1
choice resb 1

%macro read 2
mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,%1
mov edx,%2
int 80h
%endmacro

%macro print 2
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,%1
mov edx,%2
int 80h
%endmacro

section .text
global _start

_start:

begin:
    print msg,msglen
    read choice,1

    cmp byte[choice],31h
    jne next
    call accept1
    call concate

next:
    cmp byte[choice],32h
    jne next
    call accept1
    call substring

exit:
    cmp byte[choice],33h
    jne begin

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

This is the second part of the code:

```
global accept1,concate,str1,str2,substring

section .data
msg1 db "Enter the 1st string: "
msg1len equ $-msg1

msg2 db "Enter the 2nd string: "
msg2len equ $-msg2

nl db " ",10
nllen equ $-nl

section .bss
str1 resb 15
str2 resb 15
strlen1 resb 15
strlen2 resb 15
count resb 1
temp resb 100

%macro read 2
mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,%1
mov edx,%2
int 80h
%endmacro

%macro print 2
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,%1
mov edx,%2
int 80h
%endmacro

section .text

accept1:
    print msg1,msg1len
    read str1,15
    dec al
    mov [strlen1],al

    print msg2,msg2len
    read str2,15
    dec al
    mov [strlen2],al
    ret

concate:
    cld
    mov esi,str2
    mov edi,str1
    add edi,[strlen1]
    mov ecx,[strlen2]

    rep movsb

    mov eax,[strlen1]
    add eax,[strlen2]
    mov [temp],eax
    print str1,15
    print nl,nllen
    ret

substring:
    CLD
    mov byte[count],00
    mov esi,str2
    mov edi,str1
    mov ebp,edi
    mov eax,[strlen1]
    sub eax,[strlen2]
    inc eax

up:
    mov ecx,[strlen2]
    repe cmpsb

    jnz next
    inc byte[count]

next:
    inc ebp
    mov edi,ebp
    mov esi,str2
    dec eax
    jnz up
    add byte[count],30h
    print count,1
    print nl,nllen
    ret
```

It's a program for implementing far procedure. When executed the program goes into an infinite loop. Here's snapshot of the output: [image: out.png]

Comment: Debugger................................

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to use it

Comment: This would be a good time to learn. Google is your friend here. Lots of online information to help using the debugger.

Comment: i have my exams tomorrow

Comment: You should still learn to use the debugger. Also, learn to read through your code. Just a few seconds of inspection reveals this: `next:
    cmp byte[choice],32h` followed by `jne next`. So if `byte [choice]` is not equal to `32h`, you're in an infinite loop.

Comment: thanks the infinite loop was solved, though it directly jumps to "enter second string:"

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the problem is that you are having?

Comment: You are comparing the byte to the ASCII values for the characters '1', '2', and '3'. You are not providing enough information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> next:
>  cmp byte[choice],32h
>  jne next
> ```

This becomes an endless loop if the input was anything else than "2". This needs to become:

```
next:
 cmp byte[choice],32h
 jne exit
```

---

> it directly jumps to "enter second string:"

Your code is not properly structured. After having concatenized or substringsearched you need to `jmp` to either the label *begin* or else to the true end of the program.

```
begin:
    print msg,msglen
    read choice,1

    cmp byte[choice],31h
    jne next
    call accept1
    call concate
    jmp OverAndOut

next:
    cmp byte[choice],32h
    jne exit
    call accept1
    call substring
    jmp OverAndOut

exit:
    cmp byte[choice],33h
    jne begin

OverAndOut:
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```